# Using background images in Slick Carousel divs (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am using [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and its responsive setting.

This code works fine:

```
<div id="myimages">

    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x300">
        <br />
        <br />
        Sample
    </div>

    <!-- repeat divs...

</div>
```

However when I try to use background images in the DIVs and transparent inner images, it doesn't work properly anymore:

```
<div id="myimages">

    <div style="background:url(https://via.placeholder.com/250x300) no-repeat center;">
        <img src="http://www.1x1px.me/FFFFFF-0.png">
        <br />
        <br />
        Sample
    </div>

    <!-- repeat divs... -->

</div>
```

Anyone knows how to make Slick Carousel work with background images in DIVs?

Here's a demo of it not working properly:
https://jsfiddle.net/62y4h51w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try next modifications and tellme if works as expected (Appears to works on your **jsfiddle**):

**HTML for slider:**

```
<div id="myimages">
    <div>
        <img class="bg-image" src="http://www.1x1px.me/FFFFFF-0.png">
        <br/><br/>
        Sample
    </div>
</div>
```

**Add on CSS**

```
.bg-image {
    background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/250x300);
    background-position: center; /* Center the image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That works! However, I'm wondering if it's proper to use `background-image` in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Is just a styling property, i don't see why should be a problem. You can also use class **bg-image** on the parent div, but you will have to set width and height of the background and maybe remove the center property to get it fit correctly. Why this? Note that the parent div of the img tag is greater on both, height and width.